# Compilador acusa erro de tipagem quando não há erro de tipagem

Tags: c++, tipagem

Eu tenho a `struct`

```cpp
struct no
{
int numero[2]; 
std::string nome;
float valorDoNome;
struct no *esq, *dir;
};
struct no *raiz, *aux1, *aux2,*favoritos;
```

A função

```cpp
    {
    raiz->valorDoNome=0;
    int posicao=1;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<raiz->nome.length(); ++i)
    {

    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='A' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='a'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(1/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='B' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='b'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(2/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='C' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='c'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(3/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='D' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='d'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(4/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='E' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='e'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(5/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='F' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='f'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(6/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='G' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='g'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(7/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='H' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='h'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(8/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='I' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='i'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(9/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='J' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='j'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(10/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='K' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='k'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(11/posicao);
    }
        if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='L' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='l'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(12/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='M' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='m'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(13/posicao);
    }
        if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='N' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='n'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(14/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='O' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='o'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(15/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='P' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='p'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(16/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='Q' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='q'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(17/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='R' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='r'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(18/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='S' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='s'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(19/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='T' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='t'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(20/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='U' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='u'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(21/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='V' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='v'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(22/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='W' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='w'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(23/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='X' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='x'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(24/posicao);
    }
        if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='Y' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='y'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(25/posicao);
    }
    if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='Z' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='z'))
    {
     raiz->valorDoNome=raiz->valorDoNome+(26/posicao);
    }
    posicao=posicao*100;
}
}
```

E chamo a função

```cpp
calculaValorDoNome(raiz);
```

Mas quando chamo dá o erro:

```
[Error] could not convert 'raiz' from 'no*' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'
```

Mesmo a função pedindo um `no*` e eu fornecendo um `no*`.

Alguma ideia do porquê?

Comment: Eu consegui compilar sem problemas, verifique se você está usando o `gcc` ou o `g++` para compilar

Comment: Obsere os `(raiz->nome.at(i)='a')` e assimilados. Observe que você usou `=` ao invés de `==`. Acho que isso deve estar errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, olhe isso:

```
if(raiz->nome.at(i)=='A' || (raiz->nome.at(i)='a'))
```

Em especial isso:

```
raiz->nome.at(i)='a'
```

Observe que você usou `=` ao invés de `==`. Não deve ser isso o que você quer.

E então temos essa função:

```
calculaValorDoNome(raiz);
```

Entretanto, você não colocou a declaração desta função na sua pergunta. Apenas o corpo dela. É possível que você a tenha declarado errado. Mas tudo bem, segue a forma correta de declará-la:

```
void calculaValorDoNome(struct no *raiz);
```

Códigos cheios de Ctrl+C Ctrl+V são horríveis. Vamos tentar simplificar ele e eliminar este monte de Ctrl+C Ctrl+V. Além disso, identá-lo de forma adequada ajuda as outras pessoas a entendê-lo (e ao identar o código adequadamente em suas perguntas, você tenderá a obter mais e melhores respostas mais rapidamente). Assim sendo, seu código pode ser simplificado até tornar-se isso:

```
struct no {
    int numero[2]; 
    std::string nome;
    float valorDoNome;
    struct no *esq, *dir;
};
struct no *raiz, *aux1, *aux2, *favoritos;

void calculaValorDoNome(struct no *raiz) {
    raiz->valorDoNome = 0;
    int posicao = 1;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < raiz->nome.length(); ++i) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 26; c++) {
            if (raiz->nome.at(i) == ('A' + c) || raiz->nome.at(i) == ('a' + c)) {
                raiz->valorDoNome += ((c + 1) / posicao);
            }
        }
        posicao *= 100;
    }
}
```

Entretanto, acho que esse ainda não é o algoritmo que você quer, pois a partir do momento que `posicao` chegar ao valor 100, qualquer que seja o valor de `c`, a expressão `((c + 1) / posicao)` vai resultar em zero. Note que o seu algoritmo original também tinha este mesmo problema, uma vez que no algoritmo original `(x/posicao)` vai resultar em 0 para qualquer valor de `x` entre 1 e 26 quando `posicao` tiver o valor 100 ou maior. Assim sendo, como resultado, temos que apenas o valor do primeiro caractere acaba fazendo alguma diferença no valor calculado para o nome, e duvido que tenha sido essa a sua intenção.

Infelizmente, como não sei qual é a sua ideia para um algoritmo que dê um valor a um nome, não tenho como corrigir isso sem que você me diga o que é que você queria que ele de fato fizesse.

Comment: a ideia era por exemplo z=26 za=26,1 por isso usei floar ao inves de int

Comment: @user2296455 Sim, mas como `posicao` é `int` e o valor 1-26 antes do operador `/` também é `int`, ele fará uma divisão inteira. Uma possibilidade é fazer um *cast* para `float` antes de efetuar a divisão.